# How can I integrate my game libraries in Steam and Desura?

Tags: steam, desura

I have perhaps 100 games installed in Steam and 50 in Desura. There are even a few duplicates. Other than manually adding shortcuts in Steam to my Desura games (or vice versa), how can I integrate the two? I'd like to create new shortcuts when I buy/download new games in Desura, possibly providing icons, descriptions, etc, and delete those shortcuts when I uninstall the games in Desura.

Comment: @fbueckert ok, reworded to take out the software recommendation aspect

Comment: Perfect!  I think that's something we can definitely help with!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to easily do this.  Steam doesn't really integrate with anything but Steam.  I just make shortcuts every time I install a new game in Desura and add the shortcut to Steam.  You'll also have to make a shortcut directly from the game file, the shortcut Desura creates won't work because it will try to launch Desura.

Comment: However, Desura does have an option to find installed games on your system and add them to your library, but I've never had much success with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Go to Steam Library tab
2. Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library
3. Select Browse, and then navigate to where you have your Desura installed, for example:
   `D:\Program Files (x86)\Desura\Common`.  Open a game folder, and add a shortcut of this specific game.

As far as I am aware, there are no tools that would automate this process.