# How do I add the new Minecraft launcher to Steam?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam, minecraft-launcher

With the new update in which you have a Minecraft launcher for Java, Microsoft, and dungeons editions, Steam won't always let you see it in the list of non-steam games when you try to add it to Steam.

How do you add the new Minecraft launcher to Steam?

Comment: What do you mean "Steam won't always let you see it in the non-Steam games"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I integrate my game libraries in Steam and Desura?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134087/how-can-i-integrate-my-game-libraries-in-steam-and-desura)

Comment: This is for the new Microsoft Store Minecraft Launcher. It does not have an obvious executable file.

Comment: @MrParrot it is in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.4297127D64EC6_1.1.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Minecraft.exe

Comment: That's for Minecraft bedrock

Answer (score -1):

Go to Library (in Steam), then "Add a game" and choose "Non-steam game." Then you're gonna go to Browse, and you need to have the Launcher Installer, pick that one and you'll be good.

Comment: If Steam lets you see the executable, yes, but how to add a non-Steam games to Steam has already been asked and answered years ago here. In the scenario you sketch yourself in the question this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: This will add the launcher *installer* as a game, not the actual launcher.